# Prevent Windows from connecting to a router with specific IP adress

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, repeater

My PC is located right between the router and the repeater. The concern is that my PC will automatically connect to the repeater which gives me a 40mbps connection instead of 300mbps if I was directly connected to the router. I have tried everything :

• Repeater's own IP address and attempt to block in firewalls: failed
• Separation of network adapters: failed

The only way is to cut the repeater (which is very boring).
I don't have access to the configuration of the router.

How could I prevent my PC from connecting to the repeater instead of the router ?

Comment: Are the connections ethernet or wifi ?

Comment: The author obviously is worried about WiFi

Comment: Yep, my problem is about WiFi